# Changing from cs50 (SQL) to SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I was using "`cs50 import SQL"`  I would use the following code to query the SQL database:

```
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))
```

Now I have changed to

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

What is the equivalent code to get the data?

I tried:

```
rows = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", request.form.get("username"))
```